# VTK. Получение значения Z по X и Y из polydata

Tags: c++

У меня есть некоторый набор точек, который проходит через vtkDelaunay2D (триангуляцию) и vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter (сглаживание), соответственно, получается отображаемая поверхность. Есть ли какая то возможность из этой поверхности получения значения Z по заданным X и Y?

Такой вопрос возник из-за необходимости интерполировать поверхность по другому заданному набору X и Y, но простая линейная интерполяция дает совершенно другую поверхность по геометрии, поэтому появилась идея брать точку из конкретной отображенной поверхности, но как это сделать варианта я не нашел.

Comment: Если поверхность 2D, то откуда возьмется координата Z?

Comment: Поверхность в алгебраическом смысле подразумевает три измерения [z = f(x, y)]. Наверное вас смутил vtkDelaunay2D. 2D здесь обозначает что триангуляция идет по двум измерениям (X, Y) с игнорированием Z, входной и выходной наборы точек все равно задаются в 3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу с помощью использования vtkCellLocator, по сути решения строится луч и ищется пересечение поверхности с этим лучом. Может кому нибудь пригодится.

```
const auto smoothedPolyDataFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter>::New();
// настройка, обработка
smoothedPolyDataFilter->Update();

const auto cellLocator = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellLocator>::New();
сellLocator->SetDataSet(smoothedPolyDataFilter->GetOutput());
cellLocator->BuildLocator();

auto x = 100.0, y = 100.0; // задаем x и y для которых ищем z
auto z_min = 0.0, z_max = 100.0; // минимальные и максимальные z поверхности

int subId;
double t, xyz[3], pcoords[3];
double rayStart[3] = { x, y, z_min }, rayEnd[3] = { x, y, z_max };

if (cellLocator->IntersectWithLine(
        rayStart,
        rayEnd,
        0.0001,
        t,
        xyz,
        pcoords,
        subId
    ))
{
    const auto z = xyz[2]; // получаем искомую z из поверхности
}
```